# Adding points to Path.Circle first point is at 0,0?

Tags: paperjs

Hello in a for loop whne I add points to a circle the first point is always at 0,0? and not at the beginning of the circle? [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVJRT4MwEP4rFxKz4jbExb0wm8XsWWPi49hDhTKalR4pRWM2/rstBTdnbNLQ++7u+74rPQaKVTxIgrcDN1kZzIIMcxd/MA2Z0JnkFBT/hFdmymjTA+SYKrBLs1y0TQL3cTzzSI2NMAJVAtuFBe3epaoLU5WqppbM/KUKh0xUCCk3KFFTmNRCHSap6i1gq2zbQ+xDydXelHRwFvkwVQVq4tICKMQr+3mkvtOep9Nw8OsqsCgabgkF3PkKuIWRxdVkqBoDCnXFJLgySi0lnE7Dse/xpeNa+6FQKEPiGcTh73Qymt1z89LzPhnibYRWnDy729BM5VgRByzjcHVm8H5qRw70gqmXOxNFLM+JgBtYQO93PYxwbWXu4UuFUQXdfeKe9FpXM/hf5DT+zzYVoinJEcxXzROYZMxUrZRzjdVkBgXLDOoE4mgJnZPvfh5FlElseE7B6JY71D7Cd83ZoddqgmS7674B)

```
var circle= new Path.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    position: [200,200]
})

splat= new Path.Circle()
splat.fillColor= 'pink'
var count= 40
var length= circle.length
for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    var offset= i / count * length
    const normal = i === 0 || i === count
            ? new Point(0, 0)
            : circle.getNormalAt(offset) * (Math.random() * 50);
        const point = circle.getPointAt(offset).add(i % 2 == 0 ? normal
            : -normal);
            console.log(point)
            splat.add(point)
            splat.smooth({ type: 'catmull-rom', factor: 0.5 });
}

splat.closed= true
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be created using the generic `new Path()` constructor and not the specific `new Path.Circle()` constructor which expects a center and a radius and creates a 0 wide circle at point 0,0 when you're not passing them.

`splat= new Path.Circle()` => `splat= new Path()`